# Finding symbolic Hessian matrix for a function

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, symbolic-math, hessian-matrix

I have the pseudocode function `f(x,y)=x+y`, and I want to find the symbolic Hessian matrix (2x2 second order partial derivative matrix) using Matlab. How do I do this?

Here is my first attempt, which is very far from the correct syntax:

```
syms x y
f=x+y
f_jacobian = jacobian(f, [x, y])
f_hessian = jacobian(f_jacobian,[x,y])
```

Comment: In this simple case, because your function is linear, its Hessian is the zero matrix.

Comment: yeah, wasn't for the equation, just trying to figure out the syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `hessian`. From the [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/hessian.html):

```
syms x y z 
f = x*y + 2*z*x;
hessian(f,[x,y,z])


ans =
[ 0, 1, 2]
[ 1, 0, 0]
[ 2, 0, 0]
```